# C# Web API Nested JSON from Stored Procedure in MSSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, sql-server

**Overview:**

I'm building an API using ASP.NET Web API 2. I'm building Stored Procedures in SQL and linking these in the API to serve data.

I know that SQL can return JSON using `FOR JSON AUTO`, for example. But, I don't think it's the best place to configure the data and out put `JSON`. So I'm assuming there must  be a way to achieve nested JSON in the API.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
    {
        "Apps": [
            {
                "ItemID": "1",
                "Path": "/AppReport",
                "Name": "AppReport",
                "Reports": [
                    {
                        "Reports_ItemID": "11",
                        "Reports_Path": "/AppReport/SubReport",
                        "Reports_Name": "SubReport"
                    },
                    {
                        "Reports_ItemID": "12",
                        "Reports_Path": "/AppReport/SubReport2",
                        "Reports_Name": "SubReport2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ItemID": "2",
                "Path": "/AppReport2",
                "Name": "AppReport2",
                "Reports": [
                    {
                        "Reports_ItemID": "22",
                        "Reports_Path": "/AppReport/SubReport",
                        "Reports_Name": "SubReport"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

At the moment it's coming out as a flat `Array` of `Objects`

```
    {
        "Apps": [
            {
                "ItemID": "1",
                "Path": "/AppReport",
                "Name": "AppReport",
                "Reports_ItemID": "11",
                "Reports_Path": "/AppReport/SubReport",
                "Reports_Name": "SubReport"
            },
            {
                "ItemID": "1",
                "Path": "/AppReport",
                "Name": "AppReport",
                "Reports_ItemID": "12",
                "Reports_Path": "/AppReport/SubReport2",
                "Reports_Name": "SubReport2"
            },

            ...
        ]
    }
```

I have a class of the Stored Procedure in the API that looks like this:

```cs
    namespace API.Stored_Procedures
    {
        public partial class SP_GetApps
        {
            public System.Guid ItemID { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public System.Guid Report_ItemID { get; set; }
            public string Report_Path { get; set; }
            public string Report_Name { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

My Controller looks like this:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{uid}", Name ="getReportApps")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(SP_GetApps_Result))]
    public IHttpActionResult SP_GetApps(string uid)
    {
        var res = db.Database.SqlQuery<SP_GetApps_Result>
            ("SP_GetApps {0}", uid);

        return Ok(res);
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just make your method to return JsonResult ... like `return Ok(new JsonResult(res))' and make Report_itemId, Path and Name as another class, then SP_GetApps will have list of a new class ... that way your controll will give you all

Comment: @Veljko89 sorry i'm not that experienced with C# could you help elaborate on this please.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the desired JSON Class should look like

```
public class App
{
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public string Reports_ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Reports_Path { get; set; }
    public string Reports_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yep I created this part but just not sure how to get the stored procedure to connect the right bits together

Comment: if you are able to get data in App class object and what you want to get its JSON then you can simply use JavaScriptSerializer `var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objDetails);`

Comment: and if you got data in JSON format and wanted to get it in App class object then you can use NewtonSoft.json.DeserializeObject  . Like `App obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<App>(yourJSONString);`

Comment: I think I'm at the bit before that - I haven't got the data to present into App class, I have the data in `SP_GetApps` from above but I think I need to manipulate the data into App no?

Comment: yes, i believe you need to manipulate. wait for other experienced lads to response, they may possess a better solution for you